# Twitter Bootstrap and Bootstrap-Xtra

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you opt to use Bootstrap-Xtra, are you supposed to include the original bootstrap.css as well, or is the bootstrap-xtra.css supposed to be a complete replacement.

For example the progress bar CSS styles do not exist in bootstrap-xtra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap xtra is meant to replace, but is based on 7month+ old version of twitter bootstrap. Since new functionality have been added on twitter bootstrap.

Comment: So I guess I can include files from both (as Xtra has taken care not to create conflicts in the JS and CSS names), and once Xtra catches up, remove references to the original CSS/JS files - does this sound like a good way to move forward?

Comment: In CSS the lass property specified override the other. So include xtra first and bootstrap next. Same for the js. Personally I would use less https://github.com/lightglitch/bootstrap-xtra/tree/master/lib and replace the official .less files  with the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com) instead.

This also includes Bootstrap at its core, but it's layered, so you can continuously update Bootstrap throughout its development even if you don't upgrade Kickstrap itself. Having this also provides extension for "apps," themes, and hacks for things like replacing the glyphicons with Font Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Xtra was perfect for the 1.x release of bootstrap, however since the 2.0.x releases alot of that functionality has been added in, also you will face quite a few differences in selectors as bootstrap xtra wasn't primarily written for 2.0.x.

Basically, Bootstrap Xtra won't provide any extra functionality on top the latest version of Bootstrap (2.0.4) except different colours for icons; however I would suggest using the http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ replacement, as that turns the icons into a font, which scale easily.